# Viewing images in birt reports

Tags: jboss, birt

Problem with viewing images.
So ..if I deploy the report and images in a folder called `project` I can view the report

```
http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=project/example.rptdesign
```

That works ok.
But if I want to structure things, in the folder project: I made folders, one for reports called `report` and one for images called `resources`
I call the report like this

```
http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=project/report/example.rptdesign
```

the report looks ok, but the images do not show up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed the image's location, did you delete the image from the report and re-add it from the new Resources" folder?  You should be able to store and access an image from any relative path quite easily, but it needs to be stored in that location relative to the report when you add the resource.

Comment: Initially in the report, in the xml sources
<expression name="uri"type="constant"> image.jpg </expression> After that I created a folder, where i moved the image, so in the report i have <expression name="uri"type="constant"> resources/image.jpg </expression>
Both cases work when i view the report from eclipse, but when i try to view the report after it was deployed to jboss
(just copy the project to birt.war) instead of the image i get a blank square.so all the images that are directly in the birt.war folder show, and the ones that are in folders inside the birt.war do not show